# how to send randomly generated number to a users email with Django?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I would like to send a verification code to a users email whenever he tries to login. How would I do this in Django?
Any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Use Math.random()

Comment: you can use this

 from random import randint

code = randint(111111, 999995) # randint(range_a, range_b)